# Should I use role="note" for an input's help text?

Tags: html, accessibility

What does the `note` role is used for?

Can I use it for input's helper message?

```html
<form>
    <label for="input"> ... </label>
    <input id="input" aria-describedby="description" />
    <div id="description" role="note"> ... </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty finding documentation for that role. [MDN lists it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques) but doesn't have a reference.

Comment: I think [described-by](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/forms/Basic_form_hints#describing_with_aria) would be more standard. I'd avoid `note` due to lack of documentation.